# How to handle popup whose ID value in the URL changes each time the popup appears

Tags: watin

I'm working with the WatiN tool. I've a scenario where i need to check a checkbox and click on an ok button in a popup window. i've used AttachtoIE method and used the URL attribute to attach to the popup window. Now the problem is that the URL contains an ID attribute, and its value changes each time the popup appears.. how can I handle this or is there any other method other than AttachtoIE? please give some suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Find.ByUrl(neww regex("some regexe expression")) to ignore the id part. Or if you are sure that you have just one IE instance open before the popup is opened, attach to to the IE instance which has not the same URL as the browser you opened the popup from.

HTH,
Jeroen